# Is there a R function to find the maximize run within a given interval for a coin simulation?

Tags: r, simulation

hope you are doing well. So I was asked to design and conduct a simulation study to estimate the probability that the observed maximum run length (A run is a sequence of consecutive
heads or tails) for a fair coin flipping experiment is in the interval [9, 11] in a sample size of n = 1000, this is my attempt so far

```
result <-replicate(10000,{  #replicate 10000 times
experiment <- sample(c("T","H"),size=1000,replace=TRUE) #1000 flips
expe_run <- rle(experiment)     #find the run
expe_val <- expe_run$values      #values of run
expe_length <- expe_run$lengths       #length of run
as<-list(expe_length,expe_val)     #make a list for sapply function
max_run <-sapply(as, FUN=max)       #apply max function through out for both
head_run <-expe_length[which(expe_val=='H')]     # show the head run
tail_run <-expe_length[which(expe_val=='T')]      #show the tail run
max_run
})

probability <-table(result)/10000  #probability for run
probability
```

The problem is I don't know how to finish the question, which is estimates the probability that the observed maximum run length for a fair coin flipping experiment is in the interval [9, 11], even though I got the table for every possible probability. Can you please help me out? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the probability, across the 10,000 trials, that the maximum value in `expe_length` is contained in the interval `[9,11]`?

If so, something like:

```
result <-replicate(10000, { 
  ...

  expe_length <- expe_run$lengths #length of run

  max(expe_length) %in% 9:11
})
```

should give you `result` as a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values indicating whether that trial had a maximum run length in that interval.

Afterwards,

```
sum(result) / length(result)
```

will give you the proportion you're after.